# Object available when described but not available in all_objects

Tags: sql, oracle

Maybe I have been assuming all wrong,   but:

Recently I moved to a new project, and here I have encountered a weird scenario - There is a package, which I can describe and view the package body and description, but when I query `ALL_OBJECTS` view, I donot see the package.

A simple

```
select * from all_objects where object_name like '%PACKAGE_NAME%';
```

yields no results.

Note - The package belongs to a different schema. I have access to a 'read only' schema from where I can describe the package.

How is this possible? Isn't all the objects visible to a schema supposed to be available in `ALL_OBJECTS` view ?

Comment: Seems very strange. Here's a long-shot - do you get anything apart from the SYS VIEW and the PUBLIC SYNONYM when you do this: `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'ALL_OBJECTS';`

Comment: Nope , I dont get anything else apart from the SYS VIEW and  The PUBLIC SYNONYM

Comment: Just realised my query should have been: `select * from SYS.all_objects where object_name = 'ALL_OBJECTS';` Still a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that this is not how the views are supposed to behave. The only possibility I could think of was that someone has, in a spirit of either mischief or experimentation, created an `ALL_OBJECTS` table or view in your schema. It's always interesting to have one's assumptions challenged, so I looked into this a bit more. I logged in to my db as SYS, and had a look at the source code for the ALL_OBJECTS and ALL_SOURCE views. The relevant snippets are here - I don't think I'm breaking any IP laws in reproducing them here, but will delete if necessary:

`ALL_OBJECTS`

```
select obj# from sys.objauth$
            where grantee# in (select kzsrorol from x$kzsro)
            and privilege# in (3 /* DELETE */,   6 /* INSERT */,
                               7 /* LOCK */,     9 /* SELECT */,
                               10 /* UPDATE */, 12 /* EXECUTE */,
                               11 /* USAGE */,  16 /* CREATE */,
                               17 /* READ */,   18 /* WRITE  */ )
```

`ALL_SOURCE`

```
          o.type# = 11 and
          (
            privilege# = -141 /* CREATE ANY PROCEDURE */
            or
            privilege# = -241 /* DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE */
          )
```

and also:

```
      (o.type# in (11 /* package body */, 14 /* type body */))
      and
      exists
      (
       select null from sys."_ACTUAL_EDITION_OBJ" specobj, sys.dependency$ dep, sys.objauth$ oa
        where specobj.owner# = o.owner#
          and specobj.name = o.name
          and specobj.type# = decode(o.type#,
                                     11 /* pkg body */, 9 /* pkg */,
                                     14 /* type body */, 13 /* type */,
                                     null)
          and dep.d_obj# = o.obj# and dep.p_obj# = specobj.obj#
          and oa.obj# = specobj.obj#
          and oa.grantee# in (select kzsrorol from x$kzsro)
          and oa.privilege# = 26 /* DEBUG */)
```

I'm no DBA, and I'm a little out of my depth interpreting this, but I'm guessing your schema has `CREATE ANY PROCEDURE`, but no privileges specific to the package? If that's the case, it might explain why you can see the source in `ALL_SOURCE`, but the package does not appear in `ALL_OBJECTS`.